# How to properly run SpotBugs on a Scala project

Tags: scala, jvm, sonarqube, findbugs, spotbugs

I'm trying to get SpotBugs run on Scala project using the SpotBugs CLI.

I installed the CLI like this:

```
$ curl -L -o /tmp/spotbugs-4.0.3.tgz https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/releases/download/4.0.3/spotbugs-4.0.3.tgz
$ gunzip -c /tmp/spotbugs-4.0.3.tgz | tar xvf - -C /tmp
```

Then I run it like this

```
$ time java -jar /tmp/spotbugs-4.0.3/lib/spotbugs.jar -textui -xml:withMessages -html -output target/scala-2.11/spotbugs-report.html vad/target/scala-2.11/projectx-SNAPSHOT-assembly.jar 
^Cjava -jar /tmp/spotbugs-4.0.3/lib/spotbugs.jar -textui -xml:withMessages -htm  2462.79s user 135.67s system 130% cpu 33:16.98 total
```

You can notice that it took more than 30mn without even have finished, I had to halt it.

It obviously seems that SpotBugs is not running properly here, so what am I doing wrong here?